# Microsoft Dynamics Rest Api Record Search by not Formatted Phone Number

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, wildcard, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to find account record in Dynamics CRM by phone number using their REST Api. Sample request:

```
https://<your_msd_domain>/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=accountid,name,telephone1&$filter=contains(telephone1, '4086671234')&$top=10
```

In the CRM record looks like this:

[image]

As you can see phone field is formatted this way `(408)-667-1234`, and, as I understand, there is no limitation on how it can be formatted. It can be something like this `(408) 667 1234` or this `408-667-1234`. **I don't have control on formatting of this field.**

I've added phone field to the "Quick Find", and in the CRM itself I can find it like this `*4*0*8*6*6*7*1*2*3*4*`, for example: 
[image]

But it doesn't work for the REST API, so this request below, for example(I've tried many different filters) doesn't find anything:

```
https://<your_msd_domain>/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=accountid,name,telephone1&$filter=contains(telephone1, '*4*0*8*6*6*7*1*2*3*4*')&$top=10
```

So, here is the question: ***Is there some way to find "randomly" formatted phone number with Dynamics CRM REST API?*** Wildcards? Filters? Filter functions?...

P.S. That's what documentation says about search possibilities: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_applyqueryOptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use wildcard character `%` to search. Encoded value is `%25`

> %4%0%8%6%6%7%1%2%3%4% turns into %254%250%258%256%256%257%251%252%253%254%25 after encoding

I built these urls with REST builder, you can test in browser address bar itself. It works.

```
https://testorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name,telephone1&$filter=contains(telephone1, '4%0%8%6%6%7%1%2%3%4')

https://testorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name,telephone1&$filter=contains(telephone1, '%254%250%258%256%256%257%251%252%253%254%25')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Where have you found this? I mean, I read through a bunch of Microsoft docs and was not able to find it.

Comment: @SergeiSirik Basically this is SQL wildcard character to search multiple characters,  lucky trick :)